# await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); not returning to console [Post Request using Task<string>]

Tags: c#, async-await, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I am making a PostRequest to a WebApi to register a user and passing Dictionary with the needed parameters. This is my first time using Task and await/async methods but ...
I am expecting: `{"user": "TestAcct", "ok": "User created"}`  to be returned to the console but nothing is returned.
I am using:

```
            var response = await client.PostAsync(RegisterUrl, content);
            string msgTask = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return msgTask;
            } 

            return (response.StatusCode.ToString());

        }
```

If I use `Console.WriteLine(msgTask)` the needed response is returned.

The full code:

`````
namespace WattTime
{
    class PostRequest : HttpRequest
    {
        public static async Task<string> RegisterUserAsync()
        {
            HttpClient client = await CreateHttpClient();
            var RegisterUrl = "https://api2.watttime.org/v2/register";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(RegisterUrl);
            var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"username", "TestAcct2" },
                {"password", "Password@1" },
                {"email", "testacct2@gmail.com" }
            };
            
            var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(postData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(RegisterUrl, content);
            string msgTask = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return msgTask;
            }

            return (response.StatusCode.ToString());

        } ````
`````

Comment: How do you call your RegisterUserAsync method ? Do you await it ?

Comment: When you console.writeline both inside the function and after the original call you can determine if you have properly awaited the call. Your code might have moved further without awaiting the response making it null.

Comment: @Kilarn123 yes, I call it like this: await WattTime.PostRequest.RegisterUserAsync();